# The name of this riddle

Tags: riddle

```
If you say farewell twice
You'll find this one under
Watch it real close
Then lightning - no thunder
```

Can you help me determine what the name of this riddle is?

Hint #1

> The answer to the riddle is a woman's name - not a very common one though

Hint #2 (kind of spoiler-y)

> The woman is probably a golfer, if you think about line 2 of the riddle in the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, the answer is:

> **BIRDIE**

*If you say farewell twice*
*You'll find this one under*

> 'Farewell twice' is *Bye bye*. 'Under' that (as in, after it) you can put the word "Birdie' to make a film title and expression: "*Bye Bye Birdie*'. 'Birdie' is also a golfing term for a ball holed 'one under par' (i.e. in one shot fewer than the difficulty of the hole might suggest).

*Watch it real close*
*Then lightning - no thunder*

> If you are '*watching the birdie*' you are having your picture taken by a photographer (it's something the photographer might commonly say to ensure you are looking at the camera). Then he/she presses the flash ('lightning') and your portrait is immortalised in film!

Furthermore, this satisfies the title and first hint since:

> Birdie is a girl's name (albeit perhaps more common among older generations).

Comment: That's exactly it.  Great solve!  :)